# ¿Porque el parametro "cr" me devuelve None?

Tags: python

Trato de realizar un parqueadero muy sencillo para praticar, pero, al momento de reemplazar el primer array "Disponible" con el numero de placa ingresada, en la funcion "seleccion" el parametro cr me devuelve "None", realice un ciclo while para que la placa quede reservada, pero tampoco funciono y verifique con un if si me dio resultado, pero dentro del ciclo for del carro me siguio devolviendo None.

```
carro = ["Disponible"]
moto = ["Disponible"]

def menu():
    opciones = """PARKING DC

    1 Ver parqueaderos
    2 Carro
    3 Moto
    """
    print(opciones)
    opcion = input("Selecciona una opcion: ")
    return opcion
def seleccion(cr, Op):
    if Op == '1' :
        print("""
        Espacio para carros
        """)
        for i in range(0, 11):
            print(str(i), carro[0])
            if carro[0] == 'Disponible':
                carro[0] = cr
                pass
            pass
        print("""
        Espacio para motos
        """)
        for i in range(1, 11):
            print(str(i), moto[0])
            pass
def carros(op):
    if opp == '2':
        placa = ""
        placa = input("Ingresar placa del vehiculo: ")
        return placa
    pass


exito = '1'
while exito == '1':
    numero = menu()

    car = carros(numero)

    seleccion(car, numero)

    print("Volver al menu oprimir 1")


    exito = input()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El parámetro`cr` de `seleccion` viene de la salida de la función carros:

```
car = carros(numero)
seleccion(car, numero)
```

que defines así:

```
def carros(op):
    if op == '2':
        placa = ""
        placa = input("Ingresar placa del vehiculo: ")
        return placa
    pass
```

Si op no es "2" no se cae en el `if` por lo que no se ejecuta ningún `return` explícito. En Python todo método o función ha de retornar un objeto siempre. Si no se ejecuta un `return` de forma explícita se retorna `None` por defecto.

Si la función carror debe usarse para agregar uno al parking podrías hacer algo como:

```
carro = ["Disponible"] * 10
moto = ["Disponible"] * 10

def menu():
    opciones = """PARKING DC

    1 Ver parqueaderos
    2 Carro
    3 Moto
    """
    print(opciones)
    opcion = input("Selecciona una opcion: ")
    return opcion

def seleccion(op):
    if op == '1' :
        print("""
        Espacio para carros
        """)
        for i, parque in enumerate(carro):
            print(f"{i + 1}, {parque}")

        print("""
        Espacio para motos
        """)
        for i, parque in enumerate(moto):
            print(f"{i + 1}, {parque}")
    elif op == '2':
        carros()

def carros():
    for i, parque in enumerate(carro):
        if parque == "Disponible":
            placa = input("Ingresar placa del vehiculo: ")
            carro[i] = placa
            print(f"Carro aparcado en plaza {i + 1}")
            break
    else:
        print("Lo siento, no quedan plazas disponibles")


exito = '1'
while exito == '1':
    numero = menu()
    seleccion(numero)

    print("Volver al menu oprimir 1")
    exito = input()
```